# Create a class in python for a n-dimensional vector. Numpy, scipy and similar not allowed

Tags: python, class, vector

I beg your help for some issue with  the creation of a class that computes common operations for n-dimensional vectors (sumation, dot product, cross product, etc.)

I have problems just at the begining:

```
class  nVector:
    ''' Our goal is o create a class to work with nD vectors'''
    def __init__(self,*args):
        '''Construction of the nD vector with n arguments'''
        r=[]
        '''empty list where the coordinates will be gathered'''
        for i,xi in enumerate(args): 
            self.i=xi
            r=r+[xi]
        self.r=r


        return
```

I used  the r list to string it afterwards and be able to print and get to see something. The main problem is that if i write self.1 in the terminal I expect to  get the first coordinate, self.2 the second and so on, but it is returning error:

```
n=nVector(1,1,1,1)

n.1
  File "<ipython-input-9-a30c5b21dbaf>", line 1
    n.1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone knows how could get  gthis fixed?

Another problem is that i have no clue for performing vector sumation.

Thanks to you all

Comment: Think about what `self.i=xi` does in your loop. Is that what you want to be doing? Should you maybe be using `r` somehow?

Comment: `self.r` in the class corresponds to `n.r` outside, what are you expecting `n.1` to do because it isn't valid python syntax. `n.r[1]` will probably get closer to what you want.

Comment: if you type `n.i` the you will get `1`, if you do `n=nVector(1,2,3)` `n.i` will be 3. This is because the `i` in your `n.i` is not evaluated. You literally create the attribute `i` and set it to a different value in each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: the part where you explicitly say relevant libraries are not allowed makes me very suspicious that this is homework, so I will quote [on-topic help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) **"3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."** so for the other operations part we aren't going to give you the solution without more input.

Comment: hint: The methods you are looking for are `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. The rest you should figure out on your own.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm new here I didn't how to ask properly. It is for homework you are right  and the work i've done so far it was doing the whole class with all operations for the 3D vector but with n coordinates is being quite hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is with "if i write self.1 in the terminal I expect to get the first coordinate".  Where did you get the idea that this would work; this is not legal Python syntax.  The dot operator here is for `class.attribute` access, and an integer is not a legal attribute **name**.

I *think* what you want is `n.r[0]`, `n.r[1]`, etc.

Trace what you've written with a few simple `print` commands:

```
class  nVector:
    ''' Our goal is o create a class to work with nD vectors'''
    def __init__(self,*args):
        '''Construction of the nD vector with n arguments'''
        r=[]
        '''empty list where the coordinates will be gathered'''
        for i,xi in enumerate(args): 
            self.i=xi
            print("attribute i", self.i)
            r=r+[xi]
        self.r=r
        print("attribute r", self.r)


        return 

n=nVector(1,2,3,4)

print(n.i)
```

Output:

```
attribute i 1
attribute i 2
attribute i 3
attribute i 4
attribute r [1, 2, 3, 4]
4
```

Does that help clear up how class attributes work?